# Firestore batch write in a transaction?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to perform a batched write in a transaction?
I understand the batched write itself is atomic, but I need to do other writes that are contingent on the batched write succeeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to perform a batch within a transaction, or nest a transaction inside another transaction.  There are no multi-stage transactions.  It sounds like you might need to do multiple transactions, and figure out how to revert the first transaction if the second one fails.